# how to send multiple head requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, head

When i try the following

```
http1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
http1.open('HEAD', 'http://address1.com', false);
http1.send();

http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', 'http://address1.com', false);
http.send();
```

it send only first request.

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code should work fine the way it is.

Comment: it sends only first one.

Comment: Have you used fiddler/charles to see the requests go out. I have tested it here: http://jsbin.com/onozoh/edit#javascript,html and it works fine for me.

Comment: in my site it doesn't work. You can check it out here [tours](http://tours.am)